# How to retrieve no of rows after applying filter to dojo enhanced grid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I want to retrieve no of rows while applying filter on a dojo enhanced grid. I get the no of items in the bottom of the grid i.e 34 of 29 items. But How to retrieve it programatically ?

Comment: I highly recommend moving to one of the successors of EnhacedGrid: [gridx](http://oria.github.io/gridx/) or [dgrid](http://dgrid.io/)